# Update score for users in redis

Tags: node.js, redis

I am trying to connect to Redis from Node and need to execute commands.
In Redis I've following information

```
SMEMBERS AA
1) "1000:123:1603874003"
2) "1000:123:1603874000"
3) "1000:123:1603874005"
4) "1000:123:1603874002"
5) "1000:123:1603874001"

HGETALL 1000:123:1603874000
1) "totalpoints"
2) "100"
3) "memberid"
4) "1000:123:1603874000"
5) "price"
6) "1000"
```

Here in node, I need to get list of users using SMEMBERS and get details of each user using HGETALL and need to update score using ZINCRBY command. Here is the code I have written.

```
await client.smembers("AAPL:10282020:GROUP1", async function  (err: any, results: any) {
        var users = results;
        console.log("users = " + users);
        for (var i in users) {
            await client.hgetall(users[i], async function  (err: any, response: any) {
              
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                } else {
                    console.log(users[i])
                    console.log( response);
                    if(response !=null){
                   await client.zincrby('1000:LEADERBOARD', '5', users[i], async function(err: any, response: any) {
                        if (err) {
                            throw err;
                        } else {
                            console.log("zincrby : " + response);
                        }
                    });}

                   
                }
            });
            
            client.zscore('1000:LEADERBOARD', users[i], function(err: any, response: any) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                } else {
                    console.log("Score :" + response);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Thsis gives me following output

```
users = 1000:123:1603874003,1000:123:1603874000,1000:123:1603874005,1000:123:1603874002,1000:123:1603874001
 1000:123:1603874001
 null
 Score :null
 1000:123:1603874001
 {
  totalpoints: '100',
  memberid: '1000:123:1603874000',
  price: '1000',
 }
 Score :0
 1000:123:1603874001
 null
 Score :null
 1000:123:1603874001
 null
 Score :null
 1000:123:1603874001
 null
 Score :65
 zincrby : 70
```

But actually only user 1000:123:1603874000 has value in HGETALL, so only I need to increment the value for this user. But the console always print for the last user in the list. Means the for loop, loops full first and then only execute the commands. How can I use a sequential for loop execution here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figure out the issue. It wasn't sequentially executing the steps. So in redis package used in node we can promisify a subset of node_redis functions one at a time using native Node.js promises and util.promisify:

So I changed my code like below :

```
var redis = require('redis');
const {promisify}  = require("util");

const hgetallAsync = promisify(client.hgetall).bind(client);
const smemAsync  = promisify(client.smembers).bind(client);
const zincrbyAsync = promisify(client.zincrby).bind(client);
const zscoreAsync = promisify(client.zscore).bind(client);

 const userList = await smemAsync("AAPL:10282020:GROUP1") //.then(async function (err: any, results: any) {
  var users = userList;
  console.log(users)
  for (var i in users) {
      console.log(users[i])
      const getPortfolios = await hgetallAsync(users[i]) //,async function (err: any, response: any) {
      if (getPortfolios == null) {
         console.log("empty portfolio")
      } else {
         console.log(getPortfolios)
      const addScore = await zincrbyAsync('1000:LEADERBOARD', '5', users[i])
      console.log(addScore)
      const viewScore = await zscoreAsync('1000:LEADERBOARD', users[i])
      console.log(viewScore)
      }
   }
```

So this will console the following sequential output,

```
[
'1000:123:1603874003',
'1000:123:1603874000',
'1000:123:1603874005',
'1000:123:1603874002',
'1000:123:1603874001'
]
1000: 123: 1603874003
empty portfolio
1000: 123: 1603874000
{
totalpoints: '0',
memberid: '1000:123:1603874001',
price: '0',
}
5
5
1000: 123: 1603874005
empty portfolio
1000: 123: 1603874002 
empty portfolio
1000: 123: 1603874001 
empty portfolio
```